# Redirect any hit to a non-existent directory to a PHP page

Tags: php, apache, url, mod-rewrite

### What I want to do

For instance, if a user requests `/nonexistentdirectory`, how could the hit be redirected to `/hits.php?d=nonexistentdirectory` ?

### How I've tried to do it

I've tried the following code in my apache.conf; however, it is replying with an error code:

```
<Directory /var/www/>
RewriteEngine On

# No redirect, if file or directory exists
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule .* - [L]

RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ link/index.php?a=$1 [L]
</Directory>
```

Error code:

```
Options FollowSymLinks or SymLinksIfOwnerMatch is off which implies that RewriteRule directive is forbidden
```

All suggestions are appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must enable `FollowSymLinks` option as it is said.

```
<Directory /var/www/>
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule . - [L]

RewriteRule ^/?([^/]+)/?$ link/index.php?a=$1 [L]
</Directory>
```